# Is it possible to use Spark like a Database?

Tags: database, dataframe, apache-spark

i'm new on Spark. From an input stream i got a dataframe, but i don't understand if a dataframe is like a relational table. How can i save the input stream into my distributed file system? 
Is a dataframe enough to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cant use spark as database. Spark is a distrusted processing engine. You can use HDFS for storing dataframe. You can also use Hive, Hbase, etc for storing dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is a volatile storage i.e. it keeps all the in-memory. Until the data is in memory you can query the data using Spark APIs or SQL. All the data needs to reloaded back with the Spark job.

For persistence you can also save you Spark Dataframes as parquet files on persistence disk and query them by Spark or hive.